# Как перевести запись Stream'a с GSON на JACKON

Tags: java

При отправки писем, данные передаются потоком, что не так нагружать канал, реализовано это на GSON, как эту конструкцию перевести на использование библиотеки JACKSON?
Вот код:

```
         public ContentProducer getContentProducer(final Context context)
         {
         return new ContentProducer()
         {
         public void writeTo(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException
         {
            Gson myGson = Gson.getMyGson();
            JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

            writer.beginObject();

            myGson.toJson(MailGKey, UUID.class, writer.name("MailGKey"));
            myGson.toJson(Created, Date.class, writer.name("Created"));
            myGson.toJson(Sender, String.class, writer.name("Sender"));
            myGson.toJson(Subject, String.class, writer.name("Subject"));
            myGson.toJson(Body, String.class, writer.name("Body"));
            myGson.toJson(IsRead, Boolean.class, writer.name("IsRead"));
            myGson.toJson(Recipients, String[].class, writer.name("Recipients"));

            writer.name("Attachments").beginArray();
            for (MailAttachment mailAttachment : Attachments)
            {
                writer.beginObject();
                myGson.toJson(mailAttachment.Name, String.class, writer.name("Name"));
                writer.name("Data").value(mailAttachment.getData(context));
                writer.endObject();
            }
            writer.endArray();

            writer.endObject();

            writer.flush();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будет что-то вроде такого:

```
JsonGenerator generator = JsonFactory.createJsonGenerator(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

generator.writeStartObject();
generator.writeFieldName("Sender");
generator.writeString(sender);
generator.writeFieldName("Subject");
generator.writeString(subject);    
....
generator.writeEndObject();
generator.flush();
```